# How correctly defined division result for value and their lags (on the R example)?

Tags: r, lags

I design the feature as a ratio for cumulative sum and lags. But how can it be defined in a more "scientific" way, and what can this type of feature mean.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# 1. Data set
df <- data.table(
  t = c(1:10),
  x = sample(1:10, 10, replace=FALSE))

# 2. Cum sum
df$x_cumsum <- cumsum(df$x)

# 3. Lag 1
df$x_cumsum_lag_1 <- lag(df$x_cumsum, 1)

# 4. Ratio
df$x_cumsum_ratio <- df$x_cumsum / df$x_cumsum_lag_1
```

Comment: Questions about software are off-topic here. Please write out what you're doing with mathematical notation. Just posting code is particularly problematic here because the above example is not reproducible: it's missing a call to `library(data.table)` and, unless you also `library(dplyr)` (which isn't referenced anywhere in the above code), the result is identically 1, which I'm guessing isn't what you're really trying to ask about here.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaug. I added libraries into the code. The issue is that I do not know exactly what this kind of feature I design means from a mathematical point of view. Someone said to me that this is "momentum" but I am not sure what is it. So, I am here to get help from a mathematician's point of view - what I designed. Thanks